Instagram Basic Display API - How to optimize API post retrieval
I am building an application that displays Instagram media on a website.
Following the proper procedure, I use the Instagram Basic Display API to fetch all the media, and then store them in a database.
The problem is that my account has too many media (2500), and to retrieve all of them, I need to make 25 API calls (each call retrieves a maximum of 100 media). This causes my application to time out.
Is there a more efficient way to handle this?
I am using NodeJS
My account has a lot of media, and using the API to retrieve all the posts is really a challenge.

Can you share what you've tried so far? Are you sending the 25 requests simultaneously or deferred?

Hello, thank you for your interest in my post. I am using the following URL: https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?${querystring.stringify(data)}, with data including fields, limit=100, and accessToken. The first time, I retrieved 100 media items. In the response, I received paging.next, and then used a while loop to keep fetching until paging.next is no longer provided. However, I noticed that it only runs about 10 times before returning a 500 error code. Upon further inspection, I found that the API calls made later have slower response times

Do you get any error in your failed responses? GraphQL endpoints tend to respond with 500 codes even when the client did not request the data correctly. Have you maybe considered to use a library as well?

ohhh, I haven't tried using a library before, that sounds great, thank you so much, I'll give it a try. May I ask a bit more? If I have 2500 media items or possibly more (maybe 5000), and my process involves running the API 50 times sequentially, would using a library be the most optimal solution? Besides fetching all the media, I also want to retrieve them in the most optimal time frame.

However, I don't think the issue is with the GraphQL request. The paging.next is a complete URL provided by Instagram; I just need to extract it and call it

I'd imagine the library might have a better error handling in this particular case. Anyways, it all depends on rate limits imposed by the API. Since the logic to tell when you have finished fetching images depends on the previous response, you're limited to run these requests sequentially. Although if you do end up getting rate limited, you might need to add some timeouts between requests.

Thank you very much. Actually, I am hoping for an alternative solution compared to my current approach :D
